# Check and return a flag on SQL which would return 1 if all entries are 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server

| flag 1 | fruit | required output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | apple | 0 |
| 0 | apple | 0 |
| 0 | apple | 0 |
| 1 | apple | 0 |
| 0 | orange | 1 |
| 0 | orange | 1 |
| 0 | orange | 1 |

I tried using window functions such as row_number and any function. what would be the best way to approach this type of question in SQL?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i am using sql server

Comment: Note that most people here want sample data and expected result as formatted text, not images (or, even worse, links to images.) I.e. you can revert your edit.

Comment: okay.. i am new to the community.. have reverted it back to the formatted text

Comment: Please show your table structure and data (as text not as image) and the output you expect from that data. And also show what you have tried.

Comment: So to make it more clear: Your input table consists of the `flag 1` and `fruit` column and in your result you want to add the `requiredoutput` column to every row with either value 0 or 1?

Comment: | flag 1   | fruit           |required output |
    |:-------- |:-------------- :|:--------------:|
    | 0        | apple           |0               |
    | 0        | apple           |0               |
    | 0        | apple           |0               |
    | 1        | apple           |0               |
    | 0        | orange          |1               |
    | 0        | orange          |1               |
    | 0        | orange          |1               |

The first two columns are already present in the table,i just need to add 3rd column on table based on first two columns

Comment: Yes @derpirscher

Comment: `case when min(flag1) over(partition by fruit) = 0 and  max(flag1) over(partition by fruit) = 0 then 1 else 0 end ` especially when flag1 could have negative values

Answer (score 2):

Using windowed SUM:

```
SELECT flag1, fruit, 
  CASE WHEN SUM(flag1) OVER(PARTITION BY fruit) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM tab;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f5a09f957c7b98600be3916154dcdf1b)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
--this calculates the required flag for each fruit
with flags (fruit, flagsum) as (
  select fruit, 1 - sign(sum(flag)) as flagsum
  from fruits
  group by fruit
)
--join with the original table
select fr.*, fl.flagsum
from fruits fr inner join flags fl on fr.fruit = fl.fruit
```

`sign(sum(flag))` returns `1` if there is at least one flag with value 1 in that group and `0` otherwise. So `1 - sign(sum(flag))` inverts that value.